How to use a regex group and backreference to verify file contents
I have a file with timestamps and want to verify the contents. Two lines within the file should have the same timestamp value (but the value changes from run to run).  I want to verify that whatever value is present on the first of the two lines also appears on the second line.
I am trying to use a group, Matcher, and Pattern (first time for both) but am not getting consistent results.  Sometimes false positive (the values differ but a match is reported), sometimes PatternSyntaxException:illegal/unsupported escape sequence.  I have not yet gotten a true negative (values differ and not matched is reported)
My regEx file:
^TIMESTAMP CORRECTED TO ([0-9]{13})\s*$
^INSTANCE WITH TIMESTAMP \1 REPLACED\s*$

I think the “\1” is causing the PatternSyntaxException, so I escape it - “\\1” but that doesn’t report a mismatch.
This file should fail verification because the timestamps differ.
TIMESTAMP CORRECTED TO 2419211111111
INSTANCE WITH TIMESTAMP 24192100000000 REPLACED

The code gets as input each of the files’ contents as a List and then:
    boolean matched = true;

    String regEx = expectedLines.toString();

    String actualStr = actualLines.toString();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(actualStr);

    if (!matcher.find()) {  //formerly was matcher.matches()
        matched = false;
    }

Am I using the Pattern & Matcher classes correctly?  Is reading from a file into a List<> then to a string acceptable?  Is the regEx not correct?

Please tag the question with your programming language.

Make sure you use the multiline flag so that ^ and $ match beginning/end of line, not beginning/end of the string.

what exactly is in regEx? Is there a \n between the posted lines? Also be aware that \s matches any white space including newlines - maybe \h (horizontal white spaces) would be better

Is reading from a file into a List<> then to a string acceptable? It is acceptable but depends how you are doing it. If expectedLines and actualLines are List<String> and you have converted them to String using List#toString, its not going to work. I would suggest you to edit your question and add more context.

You can't refer to a value (with a backreference) captured with another regex.

Something like Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?sm)TIMESTAMP CORRECTED TO (\\d{13}).*?INSTANCE WITH TIMESTAMP (\\d{13})?");

The code gets as input each of the files’ contents as a List. Easiest to read the file straight into a String with String s = Files.readString(Path.of("x.log")); If you use the Matcher correctly with the Pattern I gave you above, you can get output like: Found match for timestamp of 1604018376928 (2020-10-30T00:39:36.928Z) This is at least what I got after generating a test file using Java 22 preview string templates

Thanks for everyone’s input.  I got it to work. My (failing) paradigm came from our current use of verification files being processed line by line against the actual results line by line.  The code walks through each List to verify against each other.  This allows for verification of expected lines, a “lines not found” element, and also to ignore actual lines that are not important.  However, once the actual results are converted to one long string, those “unimportant” lines get in the way -  the verify file doesn't have regEx to account for them (not needed under the old paradigm).  By adding regEx to the verify files to cover the “unimportant” substrings, the important ones get verified, and the capture group with backreference works as I’d hoped.
